# Return value of sizeof() in c?

Tags: c, sizeof

What is the return value of sizeof gives?Why does this program gives false as output?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
       if(sizeof(int) > -1)
               printf("true\n");
       else
               printf("false\n");


 return 0;
}
```

but this gives true as ans.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
       if((int)sizeof(int) > -1)
               printf("true\n");
       else
               printf("false\n");


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: See this and understand what it does - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w557fh7.aspx

Answer (score 7):

> Why does this program gives false as output?

```
if(sizeof(int) > -1)
```

The reason is that `sizeof` returns `size_t` (unsigned), so `-1` was converted to unsigned before comparing.

According to the standard:

> **6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions**
>
> ....
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.

Note that if the second operand has a greater rank, the result is different. My compiler gives `true` for `long long`:

```
if (sizeof(int) > -1LL)
```

Comment: What is `-1LL`? `-1` stored as a `long long` constant?

Comment: @taritgoswami Yes, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` returns `size_t` (`unsigned` type) . You are comparing a `signed int` with an `unsigned int`. When a `signed` operand is compared with `unsigned` one, the `signed` operand get converted to an `unsigned` value.

Comment: `size_t` is not necessarily `unsigned int`. It may be any suitable unsigned integral type.

Answer (score 0):

keyword sizeof followed by ellipsis returns the number of elements in a parameter pack.
The type of the result is the `unsigned` integral type `size_t` defined in the header file. 
So you are comparing an unsigned int with a signed int.